# Write to a text file, skipping the first line

Tags: c#

I'd like to write to a text file, skipping the first line, but otherwise writing over everything else. I have an array that I'm reading from the file into, and using it to store and manipulate data if the data in the text file needs to be corrected, then I want to immediately write back the data. the original text file has two columns, tab delimited, plus a single line at top that I want to keep.

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: can you paste your code so others can see what you have tried?

Comment: If you're updating a text file it is very dangerous to update it as you read; an error can destroy your file. Instead, open the original file for reading, and write updates to a temp file. If the update succeeds, use `File.Replace` to replace the original with your temp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var content = System.IO.File
    .ReadLines(file_path)
    .Skip(1)
    .ToArray();
```

You now have an array with only the content - not the header line. So modify this to your heart's content.

Then, to preserve the header line, do this to write it back:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
    file_path,
    System.IO.File
        .ReadLines(file_path)
        .Take(1)
        .Concat(content));
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to get it done:

1. Read all the lines using [`ReadAllLines method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx):

   ```
   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"File Path");
   ```

   Now change anything except changing anything at `lines[0]` to keep it safe.
2. Skip the *First Line* to get the rest of *Modifiable Lines* to preserve it:

   ```
   lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
   ```
3. Contruct the new array to be written to file by concatenating *First Line* with *Modifiable Lines*.

   ```
   var newLines = new string[] { lines[0] }.Concat(lines);
   ```
4. Write all the lines back using [`WriteAllLines method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz3b1wh.aspx):

   ```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"File Path", newLines);
   ```

***Note:** This way you do not require to make two IO calls to the actual file which is a costly operation.*

Comment: in your last line you need to make it 
`code System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"File Path", lines);`