# The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[], System.Text.Encoding)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I save the file to text. I read [on this blog.](http://backendcoder.com/how-to-store-a-list-class-to-a-text-file-wpf)

I don't know why this error is showing bellow.

I inserted Encode.Default. But it also fail.
How to fix this error?

`The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[], System.Text.Encoding)' has some invalid arguments`

`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]`

Here is code in Save and Load method:

```
public string Serialize()`
{
    return String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reportName, eMail, time);
}


public static void Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()), Encoding.Default);
}
```

Is List<> save all data:

```
public class DTOSaveFromFile : List<string>
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }

    public DTOSaveFromFile(string _reportname, string _email, string _time)
    {
        reportName = _reportname;
        eMail = _email;
        time = _time;
    }

    public DTOSaveFromFile(string str)
    {
        reportName = "";
        eMail = "";
        time = "";

        try
        {
            string[] parts = str.TrimEnd().Split('\t');

            reportName = parts[0];
            eMail = parts[1];
            time = parts[2];
        }
        catch {}
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reportName, eMail, time);
    }
}
```

> Update:

Thanks all awesome people.
I resolved my problem. But I have problem when call Save() method.

I have method like:
DTOSaveFromFile file = new DTOSaveFromFile(obj.ReportName, obj.Email, obj.Time);

This is Data transfer object.

I want using Save() to save this DTO(file).

I using `DiskFile.Save(file)` but it show error:

`The best overloaded method match for 'STU.Email.DiskFile.Save(System.Collections.Generic.List<STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile>)' has some invalid arguments`

And
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile>'`

Comment: Please share the `DiskFile.Save()` code

Comment: Here is DiskFile.Save(): http://pastebin.com/r0aW2gFF
and DTOSaveFromFile. http://pastebin.com/E0BwX4DL. Thank you very much.

Comment: And how do you call it? Including the `file` parameter creation

Comment: I call it with: `DTOSaveFromFile file = new DTOSaveFromFile(obj.ReportName, obj.Email, obj.Time);`

Comment: I edited my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, but I assign file[0] to obj.ReportName, file[1] to obj.Email,.... But obj is DTO of other class. Here is my full code Insert(). http://pastebin.com/nu8haJm1

Comment: Your DiskFile.Save expects collection of DTO's and you pass a single element. There are many ways to fix it. 1. Change signature to public static `void Save(params DTOSaveFromFile[] Items)`. 2. Change method invocation to `DiskFile.Save(new [] {file})` 3. Add an overload method with signature `void Save(DTOSaveFromFile Item)`.

Comment: I edited my answer again, is that what you meant?

Comment: @VadimMartynov, 1. I changed `Save(params List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)` but not success. 2. I also change to `DiskFile.Save(new [] {file}` and 3. `void Save(DTOSaveFromFile Item)`. But all 3 method don't pass error.

Comment: Oh, 2nd solution is not right. 2. `DiskFile.Save(new List<DTOSaveFromFile>() {file});`My fault. Also 3rd solution suggests to change method body to process single dto instead of collection.

Comment: As exception said: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile>' - you pass instance of DTOSaveFromFile but should pass list of DTOSaveFromFiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)` is accepting `List` but you are sending a single instance of `DTOSaveFromFile`. Try

```
DTOSaveFromFile file = new DTOSaveFromFile(obj.ReportName, obj.Email, obj.Time);
File[0] = obj.ReportName;
File[1] = obj.Email;

List<DTOSaveFromFile> files = new List<DTOSaveFromFile>(1);
files.Add(file);

DiskFile.Save(files);
```

Comment: I was edited follow your code. It work but file[0] and file[1] cannot read data from obj.Reportname. That show error:
`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index`

Comment: You said you are doing that

Comment: I only copy all code and paste to my application. It's run perfect but when debug into line `file[0] = obj.ReportName;` it shows this error.

Comment: Try `file.eMail = obj.Email;`

Comment: Hey @guy, you can help me how to insert data into file text many rows? I using File.WriteAllLines() - it auto delete all rows and insert only 1 rows in text file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242974/write-to-a-text-file-skipping-the-first-line). If it doesn't work try to search another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `IEnumerable<string>` to the [WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx) method which expect a string array as second parameter. You can add [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) method to execute your LINQ query and save it to C# array.

```
File.WriteAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()).ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
```

When you are using LINQ query it doesn't evaluate immediately and allocate memory for result. You can read more about [Deferred Execution on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx). `Arrray` implements `IEnumerable` but its implementation enumerate already calculated values in memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have error I updated. Can you help me?